# Is a set of integers unbounded?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, rational-numbers

I needed to confirm this for a proof. Since a set of positive integers is unbounded above and bounded below and I think same goes for a set of negative integers but just the opposite, so does this mean that a set of integers is unbounded both above and below or is there an exception to this.

Comment: The set $\{17\}$ looks pretty bounded to me.

Comment: If, on the other hand, by "a set of integers" you mean "the set of all integers", that's unbounded.

Comment: If, as I understand you mean ALL positive integers set and ALL negative integers set, then, of course, they are unbounded, from both sides. Confirmation you obtain immediately from definition.

Comment: the [well-ordering principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-ordering_principle) states that *every* non-empty set of *positive* integers contains a least element.

Comment: " Since a set of positive integers is unbounded above and bounded below "  Which set?  $\{1,2,3\}$ is bounded above and below.  $\{.....,3,4,5\}$ is unbounded below and bounded above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get you concepts and definitions straight.

A set $A$ is bounded above if there is real number $w$ so that $w \ge a$ for all $a \in A$, and a set is bounded below if there is a real number $u$ so that $u \le a$ for all $a \in A$.

It should be intuitively clear (although it is *not* a given and you will-- someday--- have to prove it formally) the set of **all** *integers* is neither bounded above or below.  It is not bounded above because for any real number $w$ you can can always find an integer $n; w< n \le w+1$ (again we'll have to prove that but ....not today.)  And for any $u$ we can find an integer $m$ so that $u-1 \le m < u$.

And it should be clear that the set of  *positive* integers is bounded below as $0 < n$ for any *positive* integer $n$.  And it is clear that the set of *negative* integers is bounded above because $0 > n$ for any negative integer $n$.

But when we talk about ***A*** set.... well it depends on the set.  *Any* set can be *a* set... and nothing can be said about it.

But  well, obviously *a* set of *positive* integers will be bounded below as $0< n$ for *all* positive $n$ and *a* set *negative* integers will be bounded above as $0 > n$ for *all* negative $n$.

... this leads to the *Well-Ordered Principal*.  *Any* set of natural numbers, (or *positive* integers, or the set of positive integers as well as $0$) will not only be bounded below.  But we *also* have a minimum element.

We will not prove it today but it should be clear.  Intuitively. If you take an $n$ in the set you can keep subtracting $1$ until you get the least element.  As the elements are all natural numbers you will have to get to a least element eventually before you get to the lower bound (and zero is always a lower bound).

Three things to note:

1) this isnt true that a set natural number needs a *maximum* element.  Although the Natural numbers are bounded below (by $0$) they are not bounded above so it is possible for an infinite set of natural numbers to have no maximum.  (Although it *could*; A finite set will have a maximum element).

2) This is true for *integers*.  Every set of integers that is bounded below will have a least element.  But a set of real or rational numbers that is bounded below need not have a leas element.  Take the set $(1,2)= \{x| 1< x < 2\}$. It is bounded below by $1$.  But it does not have a least element.  That is because any set if *integers* can be listed in order.  But a set of *reals* need not by able to be listed in order.

3) We can note that a set of integers that is bounded *above* must of a *maximum* integer for the same reason.  For any $n$ in the set we can keep *adding* one.  We'll have to hit a maximum element before we hit an upper bound.

(I should warn though that the argument "subtract one and we'll eventually get a minimum value before we hit the lower bound" is an *informal* argument and not a valid proof.  The proof, (--- Not Today---), will have to be more rigorous and formal.